# Style algorithm with other layouts

Tags: fonts, fontsize, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am writing algorithms in my LaTeX document using `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`.

[image]

The problem is that the font in the algorithm is quite 'heavy' taking a lot of attention from the other text. It seems it is different from the normal text - not only because it uses bold font, but it also seems a bit bigger.

Is it possible to make the font more light - eventually use a little line spacing?

I have tried searching for styling of the algorithm, but it seems a bit difficult to change the layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
\ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
\State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\EndFor
\State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
\Repeat
\For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
\State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
\For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
\If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
\State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
\State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State $l’(i) \leftarrow min$
\EndFor
\State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l’$
\State $l \leftarrow l’$
\Until{$\neg changed$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this may be deceiving, since most of the keywords in the `algorithmic` environment is **bold**. Of course, you can change this to not be bold... or even have colour... or even use an alternative font that might be lighter in weight (if you wish to use a different engine like XeLaTeX, say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, boldness is hardcoded in the `algpseudocode` package.  Thus we have to copy all the definitions out of the package.  I replaced the `\textbf` with the new `\algkeyword` which can be adjusted to do whatever looks good.  Here I just chose no-operation to merely print the input.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcommand\algkeyword[1]{#1}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\algkeyword{end}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicdo{\algkeyword{do}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\algkeyword{while}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\algkeyword{for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicforall{\algkeyword{for all}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicloop{\algkeyword{loop}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrepeat{\algkeyword{repeat}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicuntil{\algkeyword{until}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\algkeyword{procedure}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\algkeyword{function}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{\algkeyword{if}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\algkeyword{then}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{\algkeyword{else}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\algkeyword{Require:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\algkeyword{Ensure:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\algkeyword{return}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
      \ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
        \State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
      \EndFor
      \State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
      \Repeat
        \For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
          \State $min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
          \For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
            \If {$min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
              \State $min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
              \State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
            \EndIf
          \EndFor
          \State $l’(i) \leftarrow min$
        \EndFor
        \State $changed \leftarrow l \not= l’$
        \State $l \leftarrow l’$
      \Until{$\neg changed$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want to change the bold font. But to me it seems all the text is a bit larger than what is default in a LaTeX document. Am I wrong? It just steals the attention from the rest of the text. Aren't there any alternatives to this layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `\textbf` on your own within the `algorithmic environment, you can fool LaTeX pretending`\textbf`is`\textsf`, for instance. As to the spacing, you do it with`setspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{setspace, etoolbox, caption}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\setstretch{1.25}\let\textbf\textsf\vspace{0.4ex}}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

 \begin{algorithm}
\caption{The Bellman-Kalaba algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {BellmanKalaba}{$G$, $u$, $l$, $p$}
\ForAll {$v \in V(G)$}
\State $l(v) \leftarrow \infty$
\EndFor
\State $l(u) \leftarrow 0$
\Repeat
\For {$i \leftarrow 1, n$}
\State $\min \leftarrow l(v_i)$
\For {$j \leftarrow 1, n$}
\If {$\min > e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$}
\State $\min \leftarrow e(v_i, v_j) + l(v_j)$
\State $p(i) \leftarrow v_j$
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State $l’(i) \leftarrow \min$
\EndFor
\State $\text{changed} \leftarrow l \not= l’$
\State $l \leftarrow l’$
\Until{$\neg \text{changed}$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\textbf{Some more text.} Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]